# HOw to first scale and then rotate a model instance in libgdx

Tags: model, libgdx, rotation, instance, scaling

I need to scale a model instance (a 1x1x1 qube) in the y axis and then rotate it around the z axis.
So basically it should look like a beam that is rotating in the middle.
Unfortunately what ever I do, rotation is always executed before scaling and the result is a dear shape.
[what I get and what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9Hyp.png)

```
    instance.transform.setToScaling(JUMP_GATE_SIZE, JUMP_GATE_SIZE * 5, JUMP_GATE_HIGHT);
    instance.transform.setTranslation(x, y, 0);
    rotationMatrix.setToRotation(zVector, r);
    instance.transform.rotate(rotation);
```

Any idea how to do that?
I am trying to scale the cube to bride between 2 locations in space.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was found by my wife, who is a mathematician.
The order of matrix operations is the key. Basically all matrix operations that are applied are reverse applied to the model during draw operation.
This means that because I execute the rotation operation last to the matrix, it is actually first applied to the model.
Code that works

```
    instance.transform.setToRotation(zVector,r);
    instance.transform.scale(JUMP_GATE_SIZE, JUMP_GATE_SIZE * 5, JUMP_GATE_HIGHT);
    instance.transform.setTranslation(x, y, 0);
```